# Interpretation Confidence interval including zero

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, stata, logarithm

I'm performing a negative binomial regression (`xtnbreg` in Stata). However, I found that the confidence interval of my regression includes zero. I have no clue how to interpret this.
Does this mean that I can neither accept nor reject my hypothesis? But how can I account for the log variable?

My hypothesis is: CEO stock options are positively related to acquisition activity.

My DV is Acquisition and my IV is log CEO stock option. As you can see the CI is [-.0181117  .0211058]

[image: regression]

Do you have any idea on how I could interpret this?

Comment: You might consider using -margins- to calculate marginal effects that are more interpretable. I don't know if this will change your conclusions. You can also calculate predicted number of acquisitions for various values of log stock options (say quartiles of that distribution).

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1501666-interpretation-confidence-interval-including-zero Telling people about cross-posting is considered courteous.

Answer (score 1):

Confidence intervals partition your sample space into regions where the null hypothesis would be rejected and would not be rejected. If your null hypothesis is that stock options are not positively related to acquisition activity, you have insufficient evidence to reject at the alpha-level you have chosen, since zero and many negative numbers are in the confidence interval.

I realize that your hypothesis is that the relationship is positive, but that's what you're trying to prove. Your null hypothesis would be that there is no relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I appreciate!

But what does that mean for my hypothesis "CEO stock options are positively related to acquisition activity." ?

Comment: It means that your test is inconclusive. You cannot say that CEO stock options are positively related to acquisition activity. Likewise, you cannot say the opposite or even that CEO stock options are completely unrelated to acquisition activity.

Comment: Thanks Dave!! Have an amazing day! :)